# How do I port a simple c# console app into a Windows Store app (XAML)?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, console-application

We made a simple console app that takes sentences and paragraphs and converts them into Pig Latin. Not all that useful, I know, but it's for practice.

Now I'd like to put it into a Windows Store app as an additional exercise. I mocked up the design in VS with two text boxes and a button, but I'm not sure how to "rig" it all up.

Here's the odecay:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your text: ");

        var text = "";
        text = Console.ReadLine();
        piglatinize(text);

    }

    public static string piglatinize(string text)
    {

        string[] words = text.Split(' ');
        string result = string.Empty;

        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            char first = word[0];
            string rest = word.Length > 1 ? word.Substring(1) : string.Empty;

            switch (word[word.Length - 1])
            {
                case '?':
                case '!':
                case '.':
                case ',':
                case '\'':
                case ':':
                case ';':

                    result += rest.Substring(0, (rest.Length - 1)) + first + "ay" + word[word.Length - 1] + " ";
                    break;
                default:
                    result += rest + first + "ay ";
                    break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Here is your Pig Latin:");
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: That's a wide question. What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual studio for all of this the simplest thing would be to grab one of the template examples and start from there.

Your going to need a class that implements `iNotifyPropertyChanged`.

Your class may look as simple as this:

```
public class PigLatinConverter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _originalText;

    public string OriginalText
    {
        get { return _originalText; }
        set 
        {
            _originalText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OriginalText");
        }
    }

    private string _piglatinizedText;

    public string PiglatinizedText
    {
        get { return _piglatinizedText; }
        set
        {
            _piglatinizedText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PiglatinizedText");
        }
    }

    public void ConvertOriginalText()  //your button calls this
    {
        //your pig latin logic here

        // set _piglatinizedText to your output
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

For the XAML use a text block and bind your new properties to the text attributes. grabbing the examples from visual studio should help you with that.